# Show that the continuous map $f:(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_{Eucl})\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_l)$ must be constant.

Tags: general-topology

Show that the continuous map $f:(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_{Eucl})\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T}_l)$ must be constant.

$\mathcal{T}_l$ is the lower limit topology.

I know I have to prove this with contradiction. So my proof begins with:

Say $f$ is not constant. Then there are $x_0,x_1\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0)\neq f(x_1)$. Let $U_0,U_1$ be disjoint open nbhds of $f(x_0),f(x_1)$, respectively. Then $f^{-1}(U_0), f^{-1}(U_1)$ are open nbhds of $x_0,x_1\in\mathbb{R}$, respectively. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff, $U_0\cap U_1=\emptyset$. So $f^{-1}(U_0)\cap f^{-1}(U_1)=\emptyset$ also.

How to go on with this proof?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take better advantage of the lower-limit topology. Without loss of generality you may assume that $f(x_0)<f(x_1)$. Now let $U=[f(x_1),\to)$ (or, to use what may be a more familiar notation, $U=[f(x_1),\infty)$). $U$ is an open nbhd of $f(x_1)$, so $f^{-1}[U]$ is an open nbhd of $x_1$. But $U$ is also a *closed* set in the lower-limit topology.

- What does this tell you about $f^{-1}[U]$ in the Euclidean topology?
- Note that $x_0\notin f^{-1}[U]$, so $f^{-1}[U]$ is neither empty nor all of $\Bbb R$. Can you draw a conclusion from this?

Comment: Let's see, $f^{-1}(U)$ must be an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ in the Euclidean topology, but it is not empty and not all of $\mathbb{R}$. But then there should be another open, say $V$, such that $V=(-\infty, f(x_0))$. I'm not sure how this could help me..

Comment: @JBIBB: You don’t know that it’s an *interval*, just that it’s open. But go back to my first question. What can you say about the inverse image of a *closed* set when the function is continuous?

Comment: That should be closed too, but in the Euclidean topology the only sets which are open and closed are the empty set or all of $\mathbb{R}$. But this is a contradiction with your second note. Okay I think I got it, thank you!

Comment: @JBIBB: Yep, that’s the idea. You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What are the connected components of $\mathbb R_\ell$?

Comment: I don't know actually..

Comment: Well see if you can figure it out. Have you worked with connectedness yet?

Comment: Yes, but not very much with connected components. I've read on the internet that $\mathcal{T}_l$ is disconnected, so the connected components are only the singletons.

Comment: Yes. That's right. You should be able to answer the question with this fact. Keep in mind that a continuous image of a connected set is connected.